# Rinkeby - Not found: no matching order found

Tags: web3js, rinkeby, web3-providers

I am working on buying asset script using opensea js. I followed the docs and got it working on Mainnet.

But when I change my Network and MetaMask to Rinkeby. I get an error: `Not found: no matching order found`

Any suggestions ?

```
const infuraRpcSubprovider = new RPCSubprovider({
  rpcUrl: `https://${NetworkToUse}.infura.io/v3/${process.env.REACT_APP_INFURA_KEY}`,
});

const providerEngine = new Web3ProviderEngine();
providerEngine.addProvider(new SignerSubprovider(window.web3.currentProvider));
providerEngine.addProvider(infuraRpcSubprovider);
providerEngine.start();

const seaport = new OpenSeaPort(
  providerEngine,
  {
    networkName: NetworkToUse === 'mainnet' ? Network.Main : Network.Rinkeby,
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  },
  (arg) => {
    console.log('From OpenSeaPort CB:');
    console.log(arg);
  }
);
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to sort it out?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Let me know if you have the solution for this